# WCF BodyStyle WrappedRequest doesn't work for incoming JSON param?

Tags: wcf, web-services, json, rest, web

I've been working on getting a RESTful WCF service to both accept a JSON as a parameter and return some JSON.

This is my service:

> ```
>     [OperationContract]
>     [WebInvoke(
>         Method="POST",
>         BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
>         RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
>         ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
>         UriTemplate = "Authenticate")]
>     public AuthResponse Authenticate(AuthRequest data)
>     {
>         AuthResponse res = new AuthResponse();
>         if (data != null)
>         {
>             Debug.WriteLine(data.TokenId);
>             res.TokenId = new Guid(data.TokenId);
>         }
>         return res;
>     }
> ```

The above will set **data** to be null when I pass { AuthRequest: { TokenId = "some guid"} }.

If I set the BodyStyle of the method to be Bare then **data** is set correctly but I must remove { AuthRequest } from the JSON (which I don't really want to do). Is there any way to get WrappedRequests to work with { AuthRequest: { TokenId = "some guid"}  as the JSON?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The name of the wrapper is not the parameter *type*, but the parameter *name*. If you send it as `{"data":{"TokenId":"some guid"}}` it should work.

Or if you want to use some name other than the parameter name, you can use the `[MessageParameter]` attribute:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(
    Method="POST",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "Authenticate")]
public AuthResponse Authenticate([MessageParameter(Name = "AuthRequest")] AuthRequest data)
```

Comment: Perfect answer :)

No idea that its the parameter name not type, and the message parameter name option is rather good to know!

Comment: Saved my day!  Almost same question, but I didn't find yours just because of different keywords: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048349/how-to-create-json-to-match-serialize-to-datacontract-in-wcf-rest-service/39088864#39088864

Answer (score 3):

This is a late reply, but I hope it helps somebody.

I was also trying to get a JSON "POST" web service to work, but it's parameter was always being set as *null*.   Forget about trying to deserialize any JSON data, there was never anything there to work on!

```
public string CreateNewSurvey(string JSONdata)
{
    if (JSONdata == null)
        return "JSON received: NULL, damn.";
    else
        return "You just sent me: " + JSONdata;
}
```

My GET web services worked great, but this "POST" one drove me nuts.

My solution, oddly, was to change the parameter type from *string* to *Stream*.

```
public string CreateNewSurvey(Stream JSONdataStream)
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(JSONdataStream);
    string JSONdata = reader.ReadToEnd();

    //  Finally, I can add my JSON deserializer code in here!

    return JSONdata;
}
```

...and in my web.config...

```
  [OperationContract(Name = "createNewSurvey")]
  [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "createNewSurvey")]
  string CreateNewSurvey(Stream JSONdata);
```

With this in place, finally my iPad application could call my WCF Service.  I was a happy man!  Hope this helps.

Comment: Lets say you want to call this using POSTMAN, SoapUI how would you do it?

Comment: @ Mike Gledhill ... and in my web.config...? :( IService.cs