# RESTful web service body format

Tags: wcf

I am new to `WCF`. I am doing some simple `RESTful` `WCF` operation contracts. And, I have a question about options for property `BodyStyle` of attribute class `WebInvoke`. One option is `WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare`, and the other is `WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped`.

- When should I use `Bare`?
- When should I use `Wrapped`?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Assume that you have some contract with XML request/response and some simple data contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    ...
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    Entity DoWork(Entity entity);
    ...
}

[DataContract]
public class Entity
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name;

    [DataMember]
    public string Value;
}
```

Depending on the combination of `BodyStyle`, `RequestFormat` and `ResponseFormat` you will have different formats but in general:

**JSON** and **`WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare`** request and response will be:

*Request:*

```
{"Name":"name","Value":"value"}
```

*Response:*

```
{"Name":"ResultName:name","Value":"ResultValue:value"}
```

**JSON** and **`WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped`** request and response will be:

*Request:*

```
{"entity":{"Name":"name","Value":"value"}}
```

*Response:*

```
{"DoWorkResult":{"Name":"name","Value":"value"}}
```

***Note***: you can change default `DoWorkResult` name to you own:

```
[return: MessageParameter(Name = "MyResult")]
Entity DoWork(Entity entity);`
```

so from now this will be:

```
{"MyResult":{"Name":"name","Value":"value"}}
```

**XML** and **`WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare`** request and response will be:

*Request:*

```
<Entity xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Name>name</Name>
   <Value>value</Value>
</Entity>
```

*Response:*

```
<Entity xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Name>name</Name>
   <Value>value</Value>
</Entity>
```

**XML** and **`WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped`** request and response will be:

*Request:*

```
 <DoWork xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
   <entity>
      <Name>name</Name>
      <Value>value</Value>
   </entity>
 </DoWork>
```

*Response:*

```
 <DoWorkResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
   <DoWorkResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <a:Name>name</a:Name>
      <a:Value>value</a:Value>
   </DoWorkResult>
 </DoWorkResponse>
```

***Note***: you can also change default `DoWorkResult` name with the `return: MessageParameter`

To answer to your question, which `WebMessageBodyStyle` you should use depends on your needs and there is no golden rule here. For interoperability, one or another format can be sometimes required. But keep in mind about one limitation of bare body style: as there is only one root in XML format and one object in JSON format, only one parameter can be passed to a method. In fact, if you changed a service contract to something like:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
Entity DoWork(string id, Entity entity);
```

a service would throw a exception:

> Operation '' of contract '' specifies multiple request body parameters
>   to be serialized without any wrapper elements. At most one body
>   parameter can be serialized without wrapper elements. Either remove
>   the extra body parameters or set the BodyStyle property on the
>   WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to Wrapped.

Comment: thank you so much for clear explanations which are helpful. I give you an up vote.

Comment: @konrad-kokosa, the  XML WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare request's main tag should not be Entity but DoWork, or am I mistaken?

Comment: What if you have a namespace wrapper around your interface and DataContract? Does that change the JSON?  See my new issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048349/how-to-create-json-to-match-serialize-to-datacontract-in-wcf-rest-service

Comment: Also, do you have a typo above with lower-cased "entity" in the JSON wrapped request?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275169/wcf-bodystyle-wrappedrequest-doesnt-work-for-incoming-json-param  - lower case "entity" is correct, as it is the parameter name, not the class name!

Comment: What if its a List<CustomObject>? I can't seem to make it work, I always get a bad request from the post side

Comment: MSDN should copy paste this answer. It is way better than their own

Answer (score 4):

The usage of the wrapped on the operation description simply wraps the request (or the response) in an XML element. For example, in this contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITest
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    string Echo(string text);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    string EchoWrapped(string text);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    int Divide(int dividend, int divisor, out int reminder);
}
```

The input for the Echo operation is simply a  element, with the text contained within. Likewise, its response contains a single  element with the return of the operation. For the EchoWrapped operation, the input is actually a  element, whose child is a  element whose child contains the input to the method.

What a service expects for the Echo operation:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">The input</string>
```

What a service expects for the EchoWrapped operation:

```
<EchoWrapped xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><text>Hello wrapped</text></EchoWrapped>
```

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9db6793b-8db9-479b-825c-e781d023f6c1/bodystylewebmessagebodystylewrapped-with-requestformatwebmessageformatxml-for-post?forum=wcf