# Calling Rest WCF Service operation from C# when BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, web

I'm using a rest based wcf service that has a operation defined that I want to consume. The definition of the BodyStyle is set to WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped.

Could someone please suggest how I could read the return value from the service using .net without making server side changes?

Can I convert the response stream into a serialized object from the DataContractJsonSerialized function when the wcf rest operation has the BodyStyle set to WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped?

The following is the definition of the wcf service method

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,UriTemplate = "CheckStatus/{id}")]
    CurrentStatus CheckStatus(string id);
```

The CurrentStatus data contract is defined as

```
[DataContract]
public class CurrentStatus
{
    [DataMember(Name = "message")]
    public string message { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "value")]
    public int value { get; set; }
}
```

If the WebMessageBodyStyle is set to Bare, as the following code shows then the calls works as expected. If the WebMessageBodyStyle is set to wrapped then the message and value datamembers are always read blank even though the server is responding with the expected values. This is seen by calling through a web browser.

I am trying to modify this consuming code to read the json content inside the wrapper.

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,UriTemplate = "CheckStatus/{id}")]
    CurrentStatus CheckStatus(string id);

//Client code Works if server operation contarct BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped
string uri = "http://TestServer/WCF/WCF.svc/CheckStatus/{7}"
byte[] data = proxy.DownloadData(uri);
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
DataContractJsonSerializer obj = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof (CurrentStatus));
CurrentStatus status = obj.ReadObject(stream) as CurrentStatus;
Console.WriteLine(status.message);
Console.WriteLine(status.value);
```

When the uri called inside a browser the following are sample responses

If the BodyStyle is WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare a sample response is

```
{"message":"New","value":1}
```

When the BodyStyle is WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped a sample response is

```
{"CheckStatusResult":{"message":"New","value":1}}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: read this one first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206069/restful-web-service-body-format/20225936#20225936 it provides a lot of useful details.

Comment: Thanks. This is useful information. I've updated my question after your response. I'm trying to find out how to call the service operation from .net using the DataContractJsonSerializer object when the BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped. This is outside the scope of that question.

Answer (score 1):

will the one below work? i haven't tested it.

```
public class CurrentStatusWrapper 
{
    public CurrentStatus CheckStatusResult {get; set;}
}

DataContractJsonSerializer obj = 
                      new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof (CurrentStatusWrapper));
```