# How to modify the name of a wcf service method's json result

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, wcf

I am trying to find info on how to go about modifying the name of the object returned from a wcf service, in json format, to a web client via an ajax call, instead of using the default wrapper. I have searched for related articles with no luck. It seems the default wrapper name for the result will be MethodNameResult and I would like it to be GenericResponse from multiple methods.

My contract:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "3.0.0.0")]
[WcfSerialization::DataContract(Name = "MyServiceResponse")]

public class MyServiceResponse : object
{

    public MyServiceResponse()
    {            
    }

    [WcfSerialization::DataMember(Name = "Success", IsRequired = true, Order = 0)]
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    [WcfSerialization::DataMember(Name = "ErrorMessage", IsRequired = true, Order = 1)]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }  


}
```

My interface:

```
    [OperationContract()]        
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
        UriTemplate = "MyMethod", 
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, 
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json
    )]
    MyServiceResponse MyMethod(MyRequest requestData); 

    [OperationContract()]        
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
        UriTemplate = "MyMethod2", 
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, 
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json
    )]
    MyServiceResponse MyMethod2(MyRequest requestData);
```

I would expect since I have decorated the method result's data contract with a name "MyServiceResult" then that would be the name of the resulting json object, instead I am getting a different name for each method request. For example, instead of:

```
{"MyServiceResponse":{"Success":true,"ErrorMessage":""}}
```

Over the wire I am getting:

```
{"Method1Result":{"Success":true,"ErrorMessage":""}}
```

and

```
{"Method2Result":{"Success":true,"ErrorMessage":""}}
```

This is preventing the client from making a generic inspection of the result as would be the case in

```
success: function (returnData, textStatus, xhr) {
            result.success = returnData.MyServiceResponse.Success;
            result.errorMessage = returnData.errorMessage;
},
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add additional attribute to you method which specify name of the wrapper:

```
[return: MessageParameter(Name = "MyServiceResponse")]
```

For details of JSON REST formatting you can refer [RESTful web service body format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206069/restful-web-service-body-format/20225936#20225936) question.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your `UriTemplate` setting to the following...

```
UriTemplate = "MyServiceResponse"
```

... and edit your response down to just this...

```
public class MyServiceResponse
{ 
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }  
}
```

You're specifying serialization for `SOAP` and adding a lot of stuff that C# will take care of for you, for example, a default constructor for your class. This way you're specifying that you want your service to return a clean `JSON` object and the string will begin with "MyServiceResponse" when it's traveling across the wire.

Comment: Thanks but the service has to support pox,json and soap results. I am trying to keep the Response objects interchangeable.