# wcf rest : by using "BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped", I am not able to see object parameters in browser

Tags: wcf

I have one method "CreateAccount" as mentioned below

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "CreateAccount", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
public CreateAccountServiceResponse CreateAccount(AuthenticateApplication Application, ApplicationCustomer Customer, CustomerService Service, Option Options)
{
    // Some Implementation
}
```

If I am using

```
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped
```

then I am not able to find Request/Response parameters in browser. Instead it is showing  like

```
Message    direction    Format  Body
Request     Unknown     Cannot infer schema. The Request body is wrapped.
Response    Unknown     Cannot infer schema. The Response body is wrapped
```

[image: screen shot]

Can someone provide solution to this so that I can able to find request/response format.

Comment: For seeing how your request/response looks, you can use [my answer to question _RESTful web service body format_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206069/restful-web-service-body-format/20225936#20225936).

Comment: My requirement is to view request response in browser i.e. "http://72.5.167.17:8007/help" should show exact request and response.

http://72.5.167.17:8007/CreateAccount

Answer (score 0):

Hosting it on IIS instead of using visual studio in-build server did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you can wrap all of your inputs into a transport class, then you can remove the `BodyStyle` attribute, and everything will show up nicely.

ex.

```
public class CreateAccountServiceRequest {
    public AuthenticateApplication Application { get; set; }
    public ApplicationCustomer Customer { get; set; }
    public CustomerService Service { get; set; }
    public Option Options { get; set; }
}

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "CreateAccount", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public CreateAccountServiceResponse CreateAccount(CreateAccountServiceRequest request)
{
    // you can even reuse the existing method, as long as you don't expose it or change the UriTemplate so there's no conflict
    return CreateAccount(request.Application, request.Customer, request...
}
```