# Change WCF service request parameters to message without breaking clients

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

If I have an existing WCF SOAP service which has an operation like this:

```
[OperationContract]
List<string> GetDetails(int id, string name);
```

Under the hood, WCF generates a `GetDetails_InputMessage` type to represent the parameters of the method.

Is there some way to change the service method implementation to explicitly use this type, without breaking any existing clients?

```
[OperationContract]
List<string> GetDetails(GetDetails_InputMessage parameters);
// with some extra magic?
```

(Or more precisely, to declare my own transport type that would end up generating exactly the same WSDL and behaviour so that existing clients can't tell the two apart.)

I assume that the extra magic will probably involve `MessageContract` but I haven't been able to find any references on switching an existing operation from one to the other without breaking anything.

(For further reference: I have an existing SOAP service to which I've added a webHttp binding, but noticed that the help pages are really bad at reporting `WrappedRequest` body, which is needed when there's more than one parameter that needs to be sent via the body.  So I want to switch these to `Bare` body with an explicitly-specified wrapper type (since it does appear to be able to render those ok), but in such a way that it doesn't break existing SOAP clients as well.  I would also accept an alternative answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24691444/43534) that is not "use IIS".)

Comment: Possibly.  The way MS implemented SOAP in WCF is kinda like code-first when dealing with databases - the .NET code is created first and the WSDL is generated later (as opposed to the SOAP Java community who tend to always WSDL-first).  If you could obtain the WSDL for your current service then you could generate the contracts; types; and method stubs via tools like [WCFblue](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wscfblue).  I suspect then your parameters will change to the type you mentioned

Comment: I had a closer look at the code that generates the help pages, and it appears that they don't support generating examples for message types, just like wrapped types, which means I probably still won't be able to achieve what I actually want.  Though I'm still curious about the answer.