# how to change JSON response format

Tags: json, wcf

Here is a WCF method to send response in JSON format.

```
[OperationContract(Name = "Employee")]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "person/{name}")]
Person GetPersonData(string name);
```

Here is the format I'm getting:

> {"EmployeeResult":{"Age":31,"Name":"testuser"}}

I need something like below:

> {"Employee":{"Age":31,"Name":"testuser"}}

I tried to change

> BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare

but getting below Format:

> {"Age":31,"Name":"testuser"}

Is there anyother thing I need to change ? I'm working on .net framework 4.5

Thanks

Comment: Did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206069/restful-web-service-body-format/20225936#20225936 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `MessageParameterAttribute`:

```
[OperationContract(Name = "Employee")]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "person/{name}")]
[return:MessageParameter(Name = "Employee")]
Person GetPersonData(string name);
```

Comment: @Make perfect, JSON arrays are written inside square brackets. Do I need to change anything? when method return JSON arrays?

Comment: As long BodyStyle is set to WrappedResponse, ultimately the result will be an object with single property (which can be an array then). It does not change anything in this case.