# WCF method not erroring but not receiving my JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, wcf, .net-4.6.1

I have setup the following interface and class for my WCF web service, but am having a problem when I post JSON to it, posting XML works fine.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWebService {
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "xml/post")]
    [return: MessageParameter(Name = "data")]
    int Test(int x, int y);
}

public class WebService : IWebService {
    public int Test(int x, int y) {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

If I post this XML:

```
<Test xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><x>10</x><y>10</y></Test>
```

I get this this response (as expected):

```
<TestResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><data>20</data></TestResponse>
```

But if I post this JSON:

```
{"Test":{"x":10,"y":10}}
```

I get this response:

```
<TestResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><data>0</data></TestResponse>
```

And when I put a breakpoint on the method I see that the x and y parameters are both 0.

[image: weirdness]

I've tried posting several different versions of my JSON, but all come through as zeros. Oddly, if I remove the 'x' and 'y' properties from the JSON I send (e.g. `{"Test":{}}`), it doesn't actually error, but obviously the parameters are still zero, not sure if this related though :)

Comment: you're using `WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped` but your servicecontract doesn't seen to accept any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Amit Kumar Ghosh I worked out the answer, if anyone else has this problem, the reason my JSON wasn't working was because I was posting:

```
{"Test":{"x":10,"y":10}}
```

But in fact I should have been posting this:

```
{"x":10,"y":10}
```

A combination of thanks go to Amit Kumar Ghosh and Konrad Kokosa from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206069/restful-web-service-body-format) question.

Answer (score 1):

For this sample of request -

```
{"Test":{"x":10,"y":10}}
```

The Service contact should look something like -

```
public int Test(Model Test) {
    return test.x + test.y;
}
```

where -

```
public class Model{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer simply because it helped me understand my issue.  I am posting the wrong data, I need to post the JSON `{"x":10,"y":10}`