# Passing a class object as input parameter to a RESTful WCF service with POST request

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I have created a RESTful WCF service and trying to pass a class as an parameter to a POST request using Fiddler but facing errors like:
"HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"

The Interface - **IXmlService.cs**

```
<code>

     [ServiceContract()]
        public interface IXmlService
        {
            [OperationContract(Name = "Read")]
            [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/Read", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
            bool ReadData(Order data);

            [OperationContract(Name = "Generate")]
            [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/Generate/")]
            bool GenerateXml();
        }
</code>
```

The Implementation - **XmlService.cs**

```
<code>

    public class XmlService : IXmlService
        {
            public bool ReadData(Order data)
            {
                bool result = false;
                var path = "@C:\\order.xml";
                XmlSerializer serializer;
                TextWriter writer;

                try
                {
                    if (data != null)
                    {
                        //serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Order), new XmlRootAttribute("HEADER"));
                        serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Order));  //No need to provide XmlRootAttribute as I have defined it on Order Model.
                        writer = new StreamWriter(path);
                        serializer.Serialize(writer, data);
                        result = true;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                return result;
            }

            public bool GenerateXml()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

</code>
```

The Data Model - **Order.cs**

```
<code>

     [XmlRootAttribute("OrderDetails", Namespace = "http://www.ProofOfConcept.com", IsNullable = false)]
        [DataContract]
        public class Order
        {
            // The XmlArrayAttribute changes the XML element name
            // from the default of "OrderedItems" to "Items".
            [XmlElement("OrderId")]
            [Key]
            [DataMember]
            public int OrderId { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public string Owner { get; set; }

            // Setting the IsNullable property to false instructs the 
            // XmlSerializer that the XML attribute will not appear if 
            // the City field is set to a null reference.
            [XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable = false)]
            [DataMember]
            public string Info { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public string Recipient { get; set; }

            //[DataMember]
            //public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        }

</code>
```

Web.config

```
<code>

      <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
          <service name="WCF_XML_Service.XmlService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
            <!-- Service Endpoints -->
            <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://localhost:16999"/>
              </baseAddresses>
            </host>

            <endpoint address="/xml/" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCF_XML_Service.IXmlService" behaviorConfiguration="Web"/>
          </service>
        </services>

        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
              <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
              <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>

          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="Web">
              <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

</code>
```

I tried different approaches by converting binding to 'webHttpBinding' in Web.Config. Also, I tried adding ' BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped' into the WebInvoke attribute but still not able to hit the service using fiddler.

Fiddler Request:

```
 <code>
Url - http://localhost:16999/XmlService.svc/xml/Read
Method - POST
Request Header:
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:16999
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 155

Request Body:
    {
    "OrderId": "1", 
    "Owner": "Sam Shipping",
    "Info": "First delivery shipment",
    "Recipient": "Singapore Shipping Corporation"
    }
    </code>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40505971/wcf-method-not-erroring-but-not-receiving-my-json/40506041#40506041

Comment: @Div if you receive an HTTP 400 then the service code is not being hit.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst, yeah, thanks to letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after wasting three days I finally figured out the error which is "Content Type" :
I was using "**Content-Type: text/xml**" for JSON data which has to be "**Content-Type: text/json**".

Guess i need to clean my spectacles on daily basis from now on :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `OrderId` instead of `Id` an pass it a `Guid` instead of an `int`. If that doesn't help, make `CreatedOn` temporarily a nullable `DateTime` and remove it from the POSTs body, just in case it's a date-format-thing. If you can't change `CreatedOn` pass a 'non-critical' value like "1/1/2013..." (day and month <= 12).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried to convert my Model by converting the Id to OrderId and as int. Also deleted the CreatedOn property but still getting the "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request" issue. The passing JSON is - {
"OrderId": "1", 
"Owner": "Sam Shipping",
"Info": "First delivery shipment",
"Recipient": "Singapore Shipping Corporation"
}