# WCF responds with HTTP 400 to serialized JSON string from Razor Pages app

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, razor-pages

I'm trying to POST a request containing JSON from a Razor Pages app to a WCF service endpoint expecting a Json WebMessageFormat and Bare BodyStyle.The JSON passes just fine via Postman, but not when I send it through http-client. Wireshark also shows some extra bytes around JSON in the http-client produced packet that are not present in the Postman packet. Wireshark also reports this as  `line-based text data: application/json` for the Postman packet. The .Net packet is `JavaScript Object Notation: application/json`.

Here's my C# code to send the JSON to the WCF endpoint:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000");

dynamic foo = new ExpandoObject();
foo.position = 1;

var content = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost:8000/WCFService/ControllerV1/PostJSON");
request.Headers.Add("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.Headers.Add("Accept", "*/*");
request.Headers.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
request.Content = content;


try
{
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
    catch (HttpRequestException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

And here's my WCF endpoint declaration:

```
[OperationContract, WebInvoke(Method="POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
void PostJSON(string jsonString);
```

I would expect the packets to produce the same response from the server, but, what appears to be the same string produces a response 200 when the packet is built by postman and a response 400 when built by .Net. I'm clearly missing something subtle here, but I can't seem to tease it out.

Comment: HttpClient doesn't even what JSON is. It simply posts a StringContent. The contents of that string are generated by `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo)`. I suspect the real problem is the use of a WCF REST service instead of the common choice, Web API. WCF REST was a stopgap measure, quickly replaced by Web API

Comment: There's nothing wrong with either HttpClient or Json.NET. They are used in most if not *all* .NET Core projects to call HTTP sevices. Json.NET is the default serializer for Web API and ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree that the original question seemed to indicate that I thought the fault was with http-client. I've updated both the title and the body of the question to better reflect the actual issue that I was experiencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 possible `BodyStyle` for request and response, *wrapped* or *bare*. When you specify *wrapped* body style the `WCF` service expects a valid json to be passed which in your case would be

```
//note that property name is case sensitive and must match service parameter name
{
    "jsonString": "some value"
}
```

And when you specify *bare* format the service expects only plain string value (in case of primitive type as yours) as the request like this

```
"some value"
```

When you serialize your object like this

```
dynamic foo = new ExpandoObject();
foo.position = 1;

string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
```

the `result` contains the following json

```
{
    "position":1
}
```

which corresponds to *wrapped* format and the service returns `400: Bad Request`. All you need to do is to turn this json into valid json `string` value like this

```
"{\"position\":1}"
```

It can be done by repeated `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` call

```
dynamic foo = new ExpandoObject();
foo.position = 1;

string wrapped = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
string bare = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wrapped);
var content = new StringContent(bare, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I wouldn't have thought rerun the serialization. So I guess the follow up question would be whether bare or wrapped is better, but questions [along those lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206069/restful-web-service-body-format) indicate that "it depends".

Comment: @everette Yes it depends) *Bare* is better because less data is sent in request, but *Wrapped* body is a bit more intuitive and allows us to work with valid json object as we do while working with majority of api over the internet.