# how to use postman to test C# and .NET REST endpoints?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, postman

I have a .NET endpoint that received a wrapped request.

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "xxx")]
    public interface IX
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "yyyy", 
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
            Method = "POST")]
```

When the C# client hits this endpoint and I look at the post payload in Chrome dev tools/network, I see the JSON payload.

Just passing that JSON body to postman does not work since my endpoint is expecting a wrappedRequest.

How can I mimic the same using postman and hitting the same endpoint?

Comment: Looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206069/restful-web-service-body-format, seems that the wrapped JSON request merely wraps the JSON in one extra level of braces like `{entity:{<unwrapped JSON>}}`.

Comment: not what I am seeing. I see the payload as the JSON and not wrapped in any outer key.